# Parameter handling in custom query Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Creating a custom native SQL query in Spring Boot with Spring Data JPA. Would like to search `office_products` table with an `order_num` and return associated row(s) of data(in the real world it wouldn't make sense to have multiple orders with the same order number but in this example let's just say 'Yes' so we can return a list).

Using this Controller :

```
@Controller
public class OrderController {

@Autowired
private OrderRepository orderRepository;

@GetMapping("/test")
public String getOrderListByNum(Model model) {
     List<OrderEntity> foundByOrderNo = orderRepository.getOrderByOrderNum();
     model.addAttribute("foundByOrderNo", foundByOrderNo);
     return "test";

}

}
```

I can successfully query the database and return a result when the query is hard coded with `order_num` value of `12354` like below :

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<OrderEntity, OrderID> {

     @Query(value ="SELECT * FROM office_products WHERE order_num=12354", nativeQuery = true)
     List<OrderEntity> getOrderByOrderNum();
}
```

However, when attempting to use a parameter by passing in a value via `http://localhost:8080/test?orderNum=12354`, like below the code doesn't work :

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<OrderEntity, OrderID> {

     @Query(value ="SELECT * FROM office_products WHERE order_num = :orderNum", nativeQuery = true)
     List<OrderEntity> getOrderByOrderNum();
}
```

When attempting to use parameter I get back the following errors :

@`http://localhost:8080/test?orderNum=12354` :

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Oct 14 12:07:44 CDT 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Named parameter not bound : orderNum; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter not bound : orderNum
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Named parameter not bound : orderNum; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter not bound : orderNum
```

In console :

```
[ERROR]~2019-10-14-12.07.44.569CDT~~~~~~ o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Named parameter not bound : orderNum; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter not bound : orderNum] with root cause
org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter not bound : orderNum
```

Lastly, passing in `@Param("orderNum") String orderNum` to method `List<OrderEntity> getOrderByOrderNum();` I get a new error :

@`http://localhost:8080/test?orderNum=12354` :

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Oct 14 12:22:11 CDT 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Unresolved compilation problem: The method getOrderByOrderNum(String) in the type OrderRepository  is not applicable for the arguments ()
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method getOrderByOrderNum(String) in the type OrderRepository is not applicable for the arguments ()
```

Any idea what I am missing here?

---

UPDATE:

After digging in deeper, I realized I needed to add the following code to my controller and using the JPQL example as suggested by Shabbir the code now works :

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public String getOrderListByNum(Model model, OrderEntity orderEntity) {
     List<OrderEntity> foundByOrderNo = orderRepository.getOrderByOrderNum(orderEntity.getOrderNo());
     model.addAttribute("foundByOrderNo", foundByOrderNo);
     return "test";

}
```

UPDATE :

And of course there is the Derived Query solution :

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<OrderEntity, OrderID> {

     List<OrderEntity> findByOrderNo(String orderNo);
}
```

Comment: Your method doesn't have any argument. How could a caller possibly ask for the order 42 or the order 54 if it can't pass any argument to the method? Also, why are you using a SQL query for something that simple? Use JPQL. Or even an automatically derived query from the method name.

Comment: @JB Nizet Could you give me an example in code as either a SQL native query or JPQL please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@Query(value ="SELECT * FROM order_entity WHERE order_num = :orderNum", nativeQuery = true)

List<OrderEntity> getOrderByOrderNum(@Param(value="orderNum") String orderNum);
```

Better to use JPQL instead of native query which would be like:

```
@Query("SELECT op FROM OrderEntity op WHERE orderNum = :orderNum")

List<OrderEntity> getOrderByOrderNum(@Param(value="orderNum") String orderNum);
```

Comment: Thanks... in the native query the name of the table I am trying to query is `office_products` however you have `office_entity`?  Also, can you please explain what `OrderEntity op` represents in the JPQL?

Comment: Trying SQL example I get `Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method getOrderByOrderNum(String) in the type OrderRepository is not applicable for the arguments ()`

Comment: If u want to query against office_products table then why storing it's result into List<OrderEntity>? And any name that comes just after an entity or table name is called alias.

Comment: Trying JPQL example I get : `[ERROR]~2019-10-14-13.46.09.241CDT~~~~~~ o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method getCheckByCheckNum(String) in the type CheckNumRepository is not applicable for the arguments ()
] with root cause
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method getOrderByOrderNum(String) in the type OrderRepository is not applicable for the arguments ()`

Comment: @wallwalker you're trying to run code that doesn't even compile. Your code tries to call the method without passing any argument, although the method requires one. You should really practice with the basics of programming (defining methods, call them, compile your code, read error messages, fix errors) before using such complex beasts as Spring and JPA.

Comment: @Shabbir Thanks... In my controller, I am calling `getOrderByOrderNum()` via `List<OrderEntity> orderEntityList = orderRepository.getOrderByOrderNum()`  adding the result to `model` and then exposing `model` to the view via `return "test";`  In this example, we can have multiple orders with the same order number.  In the real world, it would not make sense however here let's say yes.